# Varying form-control styles on the same page Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Is there a way to make the placeholder text in a form white in one section and gray in another section?

HAML:

Signup form 1:

```
= form_tag splash_signup_path, role: :form, :class=>'form-horizontal',         :remote=>true do
      .col-sm-12
        .input-group
          = text_field_tag :signup_email, '',  :class=>'form-control', :placeholder=>'Enter your email address to receive the lastest updates'
          %span.input-group-btn
           = submit_tag 'Submit', :class=>'btn btn-default'
```

Signup form 2:

```
= form_tag splash_signup_path, role: :form, :class=>'form-horizontal',         :remote=>true do
      .col-sm-12
        .input-group
          = text_field_tag :signup_email, '',  :class=>'form-control', :placeholder=>'Enter your email address to receive the lastest updates'
          %span.input-group-btn
           = submit_tag 'Submit', :class=>'btn btn-default'
```

CSS:

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }

.signup {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.signup-bottom {
  top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Edit: Removed irrelevant code for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
.signup .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: white; }
.signup .form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.signup .form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.signup .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }

.signup-bottom .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: grey; }
.signup-bottom .form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: grey; }
.signup-bottom .form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: grey; }
.signup-bottom .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: grey; }
```